# How to call attached() callback in polymer programmatically?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, lifecycle

I have multiple polymer components. Inside **attached callback** of each component, I perform **variable initialization and function definition**.

Based on a button click, I want to re-initialize variables of all components(inside **attached callback**) without restarting/refreshing.

Is it possible to call **attached callback** programmatically or using any events which don't reload the page?

`How to call the attached callback programmatically event after the component is attached to DOM?`

Comment: why your `attached` function does not call another function which you can call whenever you want?

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský I rephrased the question, Please have a look

Comment: Kuba's comment is still relevant. Just refactor the initialization to a method of its own and call that one from attached or whenever you want to reinitialize again. You should always, always call a method for initialization - that's good practice in my book.

Comment: Rickard & @KubaŠimonovský -  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to call the attached function in polymer, but as mentioned by @Kuba Simonovsky, we can use another function to call whenever wanted.